# Detach an element from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to do this in one line in PHP:

```
if(key_exists('abc', $data)) {
  $newVar = $data['abc'];
  unset($data['abc']); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the function array_key_exists, don't you?

Comment: [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) But the last element of the array

Comment: why do you want to do it in one line? it's unnecessary but you can write a function and use it in one line.

Comment: @TufanBarışYıldırım and if it's a question from a job-interview ? why do you care if he want's to do it in one line ? I believe that my answer is totally legit but I'd love to see improvements!

Comment: @32bitfloat you're right `key_exists` is deprecated, but if the (associative) array doesn't contain null values I would prefer using `isset`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you could make a function for it:

```
function detach(array &$array, $key) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        return null;
    }
    $value = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
    return $value;
}

$newVar = detach($array, 'abc');
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
if ($newVar = $data['abc'])  unset($data['abc']);
```

Comment: downvoter: he asked to do it in one line - what's wrong with this answer ?

Comment: what happens if `$data['abc']` is not set ?

Comment: @QuickSilver why don't you try and see ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($data['abc'))
{
    unset($data['abc']);
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't set the value of $data['abc'] to $newVar.

Comment: @32bitfloat, the question doesn't indicate to return $data['abc']. yes, it's code does save $data['abc']